# How do I tell Python not to interpret backslashes in strings?

Tags: python, django

I'm using Python 2.7 and Django 1.4

If I have a string variable `result = "fred\xbf"`, how do I tell the Django template to display `"fred\xbf"` rather than process the backslash and display some strange character?

I know I can escape the backslash: `"fred\\xbf"` , but can I get the Django template to understand I want the backslash not to be processed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want to use `\\`, then use a raw string:

```
result = r"fred\xbf"
```

strings prefixed with `R` or `r` are interpreted as raw strings, escape characters are not processed.

```
>>> print "fred\xbf"
fred¿
>>> print r"fred\xbf"
fred\xbf
```

This is also very useful for regular expressions

Comment: If the string is in a variable, how do I convert the variable to raw? Thanks.

Comment: @smithy you can't easily do that if it's already stored in a string.  the `r` prefix is attached to a literal string.  you could try to mess around by doing `repr(result)`.. let me think about this for a bit

Comment: I tried s = "%r"%s and it seemed to work. If you know of a better or more pythonic way that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: that will give you extra `''` inside the string.  You can get the same effect from `repr(s)`.  I believe `repr(s)[1:-1]` may be what you're looking for

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the Django template, but how you define the variable in the first place.

Basckslashes are only "interpreted" when you specify them as literals in your Python code. So given your Python code above, you can either use the double backslash, or use a raw string.

If you were loading the string "fred\xbf" from your database and outputting it in a template, it would not be "escaped".